# How to place 2 listviews horizontally in jquerymobile form

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

The documentation works great on buttons using data-role = "horizontal"

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/buttons/buttons-grouped.html

but it doesn't work for Listviews http://jsfiddle.net/sHtfY/

```
<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <ul data-inset="true" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-reveal="true" data-filter-placeholder="Destination" data-inset="true">
                    <li><a href="#">Apple</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Banana</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Cherry</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Cranberry</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Grape</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Orange</a></li>
                </ul>

            <ul data-inset="true" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-reveal="true" data-filter-placeholder="Destination" data-inset="true">
                    <li><a href="#">Apple</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Banana</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Cherry</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Cranberry</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Grape</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Orange</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /content -->
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/hrtXr/

Comment: Yess! That came fast ! Thankyou

Comment: Use `ui-grid` I'll post this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For horizontal list-view, use `ui-grid` layout offered by jQuery Mobile.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/hrtXr/)**

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
 <div class="list ui-block-a">
  <ul data-role="listview">
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="list ui-block-a">
  <ul data-role="listview">
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS - give both `ui-block-a` and `ui-block-b` a class in order not to conflict with other `ui-grid` used.

```
.list.ui-block-a, .list.ui-block-b { margin-top: 15px !important }
```